# Transferring Facebook Likes from one website to another

Tags: facebook-like, facebook-likebox

We recently rebranded our website http://www.mycheapapartments.com/ to be ApartmentList.com. Is it possible to transfer the 7800 "likes" we have on the MyCheapApartments website to be on ApartmentList.com?

Answer (score 0):

You should contact Facebook to see if they will help you, but I doubt it.
You could make "mykidssite.com" get 3000 likes from little kids, and then change it to "myadultsite.com" and serve up the new content to kids.
bait and switch would be the concern, not saying you're doing that, that's just the concern.